# Missing Library in Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to install Boost from the Command-Line. I have read several posts on StackOverFlow but still can not figure out why I get this missing library error:

**fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_71.lib'**

I know there are different ways to set up Boost in your OS and there are some differences between x32,x86 mt-gd and mt-sgd. Can anyone tell me how to fix it please? Thanks in advance. Is there a way to install all the libraries within Boost?

Comment: Isnt serialization one of the boost libs you have to actually build, not header-only

Comment: What have you done? Did you download the prebuilt binaries or build yourself? Is `libboost_serialization-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_71.lib` built? Have you set your compiler settings to point at the boost library directory?

Comment: You should read https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: @Yamahari yes, I also have serialization lib with the directory but not ``mt-gd-x32`` version.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I build it myself. I think I have done so because I can include it within my class.

Comment: No, you can include boost without building it

Comment: Now It just keeping said that I missing: ``C:\Boost_1_71_0.obj``

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have finished building it but still cannot compile my project.